# Can actual Perl Regular Expressions be implemented in Java via existing library?

Tags: java, regex, perl

**Is there an existing robust Java library which implements a fairly substantial subset of Perl regular expression syntax?**

*Background:*

I wish to implement a file renamer where renaming is done using Perl regular expressions.

The trick is that the project containing said renamer as a component is, currently, 100% in Java in Windows.

*NOTES*:

I am setting aside the obvious workaround of "install Strawberry Perl; write the whole renamer in Perl (or teach Perl to the developer doing Java coding), pass a list of files to rename to the Perl renamer script via a system call from Java" as too crafty and too obvious :)

Also, please don't offer comparisons of how Java's latest and greatest RegEx engine is already good enough to do most of what Perl RegEx does - I'm fairly aware of its functionality (and can google); thus I already know that said statement might even be true; it is, however, irrelevant to my interest in seeing *real* Perl RegEx syntax implemented as a Java library.

Comment: How much is "fairly substantial"? The rest of your question reads like that would be in the 95% and above ballpark.

Comment: At the very least, you won't be able to get `(?{ code })` support without a Perl interpreter.

Comment: Can you access PCRE (perl compatible regex) through JNI (Java Native Interface)?  Not much of a Java hacker, so I don't know what's involved.

Comment: JNI to Perl... *shudder.*  Worst of both worlds...

Comment: @Manni - since, as the questions makes obvious, there are fairly doable workarounds, it is more of a "searching for a theoretically cool thing"; and thus I don't have a firm threshold. The more coverage the better.

Comment: @Kevin - not being familiar with JNI at all, could you please explain why it is the worst? Thx

Comment: @DVK You would be writing C code that interfaces with both the JVM and the Perl engine.  So you would need convert Java's String object into a char pointer, then convert that into a Perl SV structure, call the regexp function, get another SV back, then convert that back to a char pointer, and finally back into a String object.  It could be done, but I do not think it would be worth the trouble.

Comment: Looks kind of like this... http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/PATL/Inline-Java-0.52/Java/JNI.xs
Guess someone already did the dirty work for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried [JRegex](http://jregex.sourceforge.net/)? It boasts Perl 5.6 compatibility and doesn't have the worries of linking PCRE in directly.

Comment: Thanks! Would you happen to know how (a) robust and (b) fast is it?

Comment: ~10% faster than java.util.regex, much slower than native Perl.

Comment: Should be fairly robust. Haven't tested it for named grouping or anything.

Comment: Sux re: performance. I'm probably just going to batch off the list of strings and regexes and call a Perl script on the batch then... +1 nevertheless for excellent suggestion!

Answer (score 5):

For maximum Perl compatibility you would need to actually use Perl. You can do that using 
[Inline::Java::Callback](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::Java::Callback), which is distributed as part of the [Inline::Java](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::Java) module.

See also: [How can I call Perl from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274840/how-can-i-call-perl-from-java)

Answer (score 3):

The library you are looking for is the [Apache ORO](http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/) library, it is specifically implemented to handle Perl5 regular expressions.

Comment: Just as a note, the stable version only supports Perl5.003 as per their docs. But a good option nonetheless!