# How to efficiently call Perl program from Java?

Tags: java, perl

I am trying to run a Perl program in Java.

I'm using:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getComps.pl");
```

but it is giving:

> Exception: java.io.IOException: Cannot
>   run program "getComps.pl":
>   CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a
>   valid Win32 application

I have also tried:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start getComps.pl");
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c call getComps.pl");
```

But this is not giving any output.

It is giving the empty file after executing the program and taking lots of time to execute.

Is there an efficient way to call a Perl program from Java?

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine the problem you're having is that a perl script isn't executable on it's own, you need to invoke Perl itself. Using your current approach you can probably just do the following:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl getComps.pl")
```

But there are other options, take a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274840/how-can-i-call-perl-from-java).

Comment: This will only look in the current directory for getComps.pl.  To look on the PATH: "perl -S getComps.pl"

Answer (score 0):

Have any one tried `Perl2EXE`? With this you can convert your perl to `EXE` and then call:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getComps <ARGS>")
```